# What methods are there to develop iPhone app on windows that compiles on Xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, windows

Not asking for mac on pc.
My friend could compile the app on his computer, so I just wondered if there is a way to write the app on windows (would need simulater) that can then be "copy and pasted" into Xcode to compile it.

Dragonfire sdk is this is think, but are there, free-er, alternatives?

Native app - not phonegap  or the such

Comment: HTML5. PhoneGap or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write these shared programs using a language which is well supported on all platforms, such as C++.

You can run the c++ programs natively on either platform, the iOS Simulator, and iOS Devices. The iOS Simulator and the Xcode toolset require OS X.

Using C++ alone, your friend can write a significant portion of an iOS program, but not all of it (unless you find some library which implements this scaffolding - I do not know of one). This way, your friend could write much of the backend, and you could tie those programs into the necessary points of the iOS app interfaces.

It may help to provide your friend with a list of libraries distributed with the OS version you target. QuartzCore.framework (for example) will not be available on Windows, but several of the system C/C++ libraries may be available on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any simulator of that kind. You'd need Foundation and AppKit at least. The only way I see it's possible is developin using C++ and creating everything from scratch. I'd tend to say it's not doable.